# There have strips on the Unity2D sprites in build mode

Tags: unity-game-engine, renderer

The sprite renderer can render the sprite correctly in the Unity Play mode, but when I build the game, it can't render the sprite correctly, and there are strips on the sprite. Here are the screenshots:

[sprite rendered in Unity embedded play mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSLnM.png)

[sprite rendered in Unity Build mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7vQk.png)

Comment: I had similar problem. Fixed it by playing around sprite's compression settings. Try different settings of compression.

Comment: I've tried to low down the resolution ratio of the image. For example, 1000x1000 low down to 200x200. Then I replace the high one and then low down PPU. It only works for some sprites without animation.

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. So every sprite renders like that? Or every sprite that has no animation?

Comment: Only some of the sprites are rendered like that. And for each sprite that has animation, in some frames of the animation, the sprite is rendered like that, so the animation looks weird.

Comment: Yeah. I can imagine how it looks. Is your animation 60 fps? How many fps are you getting? How much ram is your computer?

Comment: I remember in my wrestling game (that I'm currently working on) animations were 60 fps and everything was high quality. And sprites were acting just like yours. So I did some optimization (using YouTube video). Got +10, +20 fps and sprites started rendering normally. I think that's what's going on here. But I'm not sure. Try creating new "test" scene with one sprite in it and see if it is still acting weird

Comment: Yes, the animation has sample 60. In the Unity Game Window, I got over 1000FPS. And my computer has 48GB RAM, so I don't think there would have a bottleneck in my computer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246923/discussion-between-ygreater-and-vinkle).

Answer (score 0):

Try ESTC compression. It is recommended by Unity.